# How to run a jar file from a Windows Service

Tags: c#, java, windows, jar, windows-services

I have written a WPF app in which i can input my dos command and get a message box with the response using C# and its working quite well. Now i want to write a service which can execute a the command "*java -jar myfile.jar*" at intervals. The jar file is accessing a weblogic queue and returning the results which are read by the Function below. Problem is the service is not working, despite the function below having worked succesfully in WFP.

**How do I get this function to work in Windows Services?**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes a shell command synchronously.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="command">string command</param>
    /// <returns>string, as output of the command.</returns>
    public void ExecuteCommandSync(object command)
    {
     try
     {
         // create the ProcessStartInfo using "cmd" as the program to be run,
         // and "/c " as the parameters.
         // Incidentally, /c tells cmd that we want it to execute the command that follows,
         // and then exit.
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
        new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);

    // The following commands are needed to redirect the standard output.
    // This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
    procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    // Do not create the black window.
    procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    // Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
    proc.Start();
    // Get the output into a string
    string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    // Display the command output.
    Console.WriteLine(result);
      }
      catch (Exception objException)
      {
      // Log the exception
      }
}
```

code obtained from [codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25983/How-to-Execute-a-Command-in-C)

Comment: What is the full command line that you are trying to run?

Comment: And are you running the service in the account where you installed Java, or in the LocalSystem account (the default)? Since you never installed Java as LocalSystem, it may not work properly there.

Comment: @CoreTech I am running in the same account. The following command

Comment: You forgot to include the command?

Comment: @CoreTech The command is `java -jar c:/myApp.jar`. My apologies for the previous comment that is incomplete, I thought I edited earlier. It is running well when called from the WPF function. I have however discovered that the command is executing if I call the function OnStart and OnStop. But not being called in the Timer. I am using System.Timer.Timer.

Comment: Try specifying the full path to java, like this: "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -jar "c:\myApp.jar". Of course, please use your own location! It is best to be precise instead of assuming that java is in the path.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "it does not work"? Does your code fail with an error or exception? If so, please let us know the details.

Comment: @CoreTech After some testing and investigating I found that the function `ExecuteCommandSync(object command)` was executing if called outside the timer, otherwise it wouldn't be executed. **No exceptions are being thrown at all**. I was enabling my timer in the `OnStart()` method but when I set `myTimer.Enabled = true` from the constructor the code worked like a charm. **Thanx for your attention and most valued assistance :)**